# How to insert plain text?

Tags: latex, tex

I have some xml text to be inserted in the document as plain text. I directly inserted but it gives weird symbols. How can I avoid that?

XML I want to add:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|}

<table>
<tr>
<td> Title and Logo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> left Column </td>
<td> main table </td>
</tr>
</table>


\end{tabular}
```

And the output is like :

```
¡table¿ ¡tr¿ ¡td¿ Title and Logo¡/td¿ ¡/tr¿ ¡tr¿ ¡td¿ left Column ¡/td¿ ¡td¿ main table ¡/td¿ ¡/tr¿ ¡/table
```

Basically I want to add the HTML code in a tabular. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "weird symbols"?

Comment: You can fix this with a different encoding. See [Why do the less than symbol (`<`) and the greater than symbol (`>`) appear wrong as upside down exclamation or question mark?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2369/5764)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Have you tried the `verbatim` environment?

```
\begin{verbatim}
  Your text here.
\end{verbatim}
```

Without knowing what your "weird symbols" are, it's difficult to suggest a solution to your problem.

---

**Update:** In order to embed a `verbatim` environment in a table cell, you need to change the column to a paragraph column (using either `p`, `m`, or `b` as the column specifier); e.g.

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{10cm}|}
  \begin{verbatim}
    Your text here.
  \end{verbatim}
\end{tabular}
```

See [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Other_environments_inside_tables) for more information.

Comment: I tried to add the begin verbatim in the tabular but it does not compile

Comment: @texasbruce ...so what error message does it fail with?

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.186 \begin{verbatim}
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.`